# How to express the meaning of "less close to each other"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

By "such activities",  I mean leisure activities like going out to dinner with friends. I remember that I learned somewhere that "alienated" implies mental conflicts. But here I just want to say they may gradually become less close to each other. What word should I use?

> Without such activities to bond, they may gradually become **alienated**
> from each other.

Comment: "They may gradually drift apart"?

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you. Do I still need "gradually" if I use "drift apart"? According  to the dictionary, "drift apart" already has the meaning of "gradually".

Comment: Also, does "drift apart" must have the meaning of "end"? I mean the relationship eventually ends.

Comment: No, _gradually_ is not essential. If two people are apart, they are no longer together, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word you could use is *distant*.

In connection with relationships, 'distant' means "less close", either physically (seeing less of a person) or emotionally (speaking less, or having less depth to the relationship). This can be a result of two people just 'drifting' apart. By contrast, 'alienated' is more one-sided. One can deliberately alienate another person by pushing them out, or one can *feel* alienated.

Comment: ... dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alienated